# Equivalent definition of Lipschitz continuity in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, definition, lipschitz-functions

We know that a function $f:\,\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) if exists a real constant $C>0$ such that $$\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|\leq C\left|x-y\right|\tag{1}$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Now assume that for all $\epsilon>0$ exists a $C=C\left(\epsilon\right)>0$ such that $$\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|\leq C\left(\epsilon\right)\left|x-y\right|\tag{2}$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\left|x-y\right|>\epsilon$. My question is:

> are these definitions equivalent?

It is obvious that $\left(1\right)\Rightarrow\left(2\right)$ but I'm not sure about the other implication. I tried to prove it by absurd but I get nothing.

Comment: Hint: consider the function $x \mapsto \sqrt{|x|}$, in a neighbourhood of 0. This function is not Lipschitz but satisfies the second definition.

Comment: @snefs Thank you, I will try to follow your hint

Comment: What made you choose $|x-y|>\epsilon$?

Comment: @Sudix A problem I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean to write $|x-y|<\epsilon$ at the end there. The definitions are not equivalent in general. We call the functions satisfying $(2)$ locally Lipschitz continuous. If your space is nice enough, i.e. locally compact, then we have $f$ is locally Lipschitz iff $f$ is Lipschitz on every compact subset of the space.

Comment: Thank you but no, I mean $\left|x-y\right|>\epsilon.$